# Is there a general way to do partial fractions with trig functions?

Tags: calculus, partial-fractions

Consider $$1 \over \sin (x - a) \sin (x - b)$$

I rewrite it as $${A \over \sin (x - a)} + {B \over \sin (x - b)} = {1 \over \sin (x - a) \sin (x - b)}$$

Then multiplying by $\sin (x - a)$,

$$A = {1 \over \sin (x - b)} - {B\sin (x - a) \over \sin (x - b)}$$

If I put $x = a$, then I get $$A = {1 \over \sin (a - b)}$$,

Similarly I get $$B = { 1\over \sin(b - a)}$$.

But this does not seem correct as I plugged it back in and I don't get the original function.

What is the general way of doing partial fraction for trigonometric functions like $$1 \over \cos(x - a)\cos (x - b)$$ or the example above.

Comment: You may be OK. Try the identity here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities

Comment: @EthanBolker I doubt that because the right partial fraction is $$\operatorname{cosec}(a - b) \left({\cos (x - a) \over \sin(x - a)} -{\cos (x - b) \over \sin(x - b)} \right)$$

Comment: In case it's of interest, Michael Hardy's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1126785/86418) to [Partial fractions and trig functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1126736) gives the standard algorithm (the tangent half-angle substitution) for converting a rational function of sines and cosines into a rational function.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thank you. I actually overlooked that answer while researching this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The partial fration method that you advocate (with constants in the numerators) only works for polynomials. So your ansatz
$$
{A \over \sin (x - a)} + {B \over \sin (x - b)} = {1 \over \sin (x - a) \sin (x - b)}
$$
will produce wrong results.

A more general way of proceeding is to write the numerators as functions:

$$
{A(x) \over \sin (x - a)} + {B(x) \over \sin (x - b)} = {1 \over \sin (x - a) \sin (x - b)}
$$

Clearing denominators gives
$$
1 = {A(x) \sin (x - b)} + {B(x) \sin (x - a)}
$$

Since $ \sinα \cos β= 1/2 (\sin(α - β) + \sin(α + β))$ and $ \sinβ \cos α= 1/2 (- \sin(α - β) + \sin(α + β))$ one can write $A(x) = q \cos(x-a)$ and $B(x) = - q \cos(x-b)$ with some constant $q$ to be determined. This gives

$$
1 = {q \cos(x-a) \sin (x - b)} - {q \cos(x-b) \sin (x - a)} =  q \sin(a-b)
$$

so

$$
q = \frac{1}{\sin(a-b)} = \operatorname{cosec} (a-b)$$

as required. The general way of proceeding is to make use of those trig relations.

By the same method, you get

$$
{1 \over \cos (x - a) \cos (x - b)} = - \operatorname{cosec}(a - b) \left({\sin (x - a) \over \cos(x - a)} -{\sin (x - b) \over \cos(x - b)} \right)
$$

Comment: I did not understand how knowing $\sinα \cos β= 1/2 (\sin(α - β) + \sin(α + β))$ and $\sinβ \cos α= 1/2 (- \sin(α - β) + \sin(α + β))$ told you that $A(x) = q \cos(x-a)$ and $B(x) = - q \cos(x-b)$ ? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: From  the form $1 = {A(x) \sin (x - b)} + {B(x) \sin (x - a)}$, you are looking for $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ to get rid of the $x$-dependency on the RHS. The trig identities which I gave do exactly that, so I chose $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ accordingly, where the constant $q$ is introduced to equate with the LHS.

Comment: Admittedly, my solution relies on some intuition on trig relations. Michael Hardy's answer to Partial fractions and trig functions (as communicated  by Andrew D. Hwang above) is more principled, in cases where such intuition doesn't come that obviously.

Comment: Yes got it, thank for the answer.